# Pivot/reshape and create new columns

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, reshape

My dataframe

```
City   Ind: Money    Position Money    Ind: Health   Position Health 
NY       6             5                   4          3
LA       2             1                   9          8
BA       7             11                 13          15
```

Desired dataframe

```
 Ind   Position_NY  Position_LA  Position_BA   Ind_NY  Ind_LA Ind_BA   
Money      5          1            11           6       2        7
Health     3          8            15           4       9        13
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help you?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
~City, ~`Ind: Money`,    ~`Position Money`,    ~`Ind: Health`,   ~`Position Health` ,
"NY", 6, 5, 4, 3,
"LA", 2, 1 , 9, 8,
"BA", 7, 11, 13, 15
)

data <- pivot_longer(df, cols = starts_with(c("Ind", "Position"))) %>% 
  separate(name, c("var", "Ind")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("City", "var"))
```

Comment: I already solved but with more lines! Thank you, this way is cleaner